# Hibernate: update many to many with extra columns relationship

Tags: hibernate

I have trouble with Hibernate and manyToMany relationship with extra-columns, below my code:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "XXX", name = "YYY")
@Audited
public class TransactionEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long transactionId;

  // fields

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<TransactionTagEntity> tags;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "XXX", name = "ZZZ")
@Audited
public class TagEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long tagId;

  // fields
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "XXX", name = "YYY_ZZZ")
@Audited
public class TransactionTagEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @EmbeddedId
  private TransactionTagPk pk;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("transactionId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transactionId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private TransactionEntity transaction;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("tagId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "tagId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private TagEntity tag;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Embeddable
public class TransactionTagPk implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "transaction_id")
  private Long transactionId;

  @Column(name = "tag_id")
  private Long tagId;
}
```

In the persistence adapter I've a method that received the ID of transaction and a list of ID of existing tags. Firstly, I look for the transaction by its ID, than I search for the tags and build a list of transaction entities. Then, I delete all the tags associated with the transaction and insert the newly created list. Finally, I save the transaction.

My code below:

```
@Override
public void addTags(long transactionId, List<Long> tagsId) {
  Optional<TransactionEntity> transactionEntity = transactionRepository.findById(transactionId);
  if (transactionEntity.isEmpty()) {
    throw new ForeignKeyConstraintViolatedException("Transaction not found");
  }

  List<TransactionTagEntity> transactionTagEntityList = tagsId.stream().map(tagId -> buildTransactionTagEntity(transactionEntity.get(), tagId)).toList();
  transactionEntity.get().getTags().clear();
  transactionEntity.get().setTags(transactionTagEntityList);

  transactionRepository.save(transactionEntity.get());
}

private TransactionTagEntity buildTransactionTagEntity(final TransactionEntity entity, final long tagId) {
  TagEntity tagEntity = tagRepository.findById(tagId).orElseThrow(() -> new ForeignKeyConstraintViolatedException("Tag not found"));
  return new TransactionTagEntity(entity, tagEntity);
}
```

Executing this code I've the error below at the save action:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using this code in transaction entity:

```
public void addTags(List<TransactionTagEntity> tags) {
    if (this.tags != null) {
        this.tags.clear();
        this.tags.addAll(tags);
    } else {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```